# Do member variables die off before the destructor is called?

Tags: c++

I was running this code to figure out which whether an object is destructed after or before it is reassigned to. But I didn't get the expected output. The variable `id` is printed correctly by the included `print` function, but it fails with some other number when printed by the destructor, and the two are the same for both objects. Why does this happen?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
    static int _idx;
    int id;
public:
    A()
    {
    std::cout << "Default constructor" << std::endl;
    id = _idx;
    _idx++;
    }
    A(std::string&& str)
    { 
    id = _idx;
    _idx++;
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
    void print()
    {
    std::cout << id << std::endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
    std::cout << id << std::endl;
    }
};

int A::_idx = 0;



int main(void)
{
    A a;
    a.print();
    a = std::string("World");
 }
```

Output:

```
Default constructor
0
World
1
1
```

EDIT: Removed sloppy code and added example output for clarification

Comment: `a.~A();` simply don't do that!

Comment: If members were destroyed before the destructor was called, how could the destructor do any meaningful work with the members?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Again, I realize I'm being VERY hacky here, but I'm just trying to learn how things work at a lower level, not writing actual code, so forgive the obviously bad piece of code.

Comment: @ShaheAnsar In the future, you can call the destructor "explicitly" by letting it go out of scope. Like this, for example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/3GDmIHhkVWVdUqTg

Comment: @Justin Why would the members be destroyed before the destructor is called though? If that were the case, a pointer pointing to some heap allocated memory wouldn't be able to be deleted, which obviously isn't the case.

Comment: @ShaheAnsar Exactly.

Comment: A hint: there are multiple objects in play here. There are multiple instances of `A`, and not all of them were created through the default constructor. One of them has an uninitialized `id`

Comment: @Justin OK, I fixed that part, and added an id initialization in the other constructor. The output still shows that the destructor runs twice but shows the same id

Comment: @ShaheAnsar See the rule of 3/5: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: @Bathsheba Done. Comment moved to answer.

Comment: Regarding the un-asked question, does this help you visualize what's really going on here: https://ideone.com/olLGQS ?

Comment: @user4581301 I've changed the code a bit since there was an error in it, could you look at it again?

Comment: Take care editing the question once answers start rolling in. The downside of that edit is it made rsahu's excellent answer mostly redundant. Does this one demonstrate the problem better: https://ideone.com/IQ8HMy ?

Comment: @user4581301 Yup. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Don't** call the destructor explicitly. Simply allow the variable to go out of scope.

When `A` does go out of scope, the first thing to run is the destructor body, followed by any destructors for member variables in the class *in the reverse order in which they are constructed*, then the process continues for any base classes.

(Member variables are constructed in the order that they appear in the class declaration.)

In your code, the destructor is called twice since you constructing 2 instances of `A`; note that the compiler generated assignment operator is effectively the thing that causes the value of `id` to be 1 at the point of their destruction.

Comment: I've fixed that part, into something more "digestible". The problem I asked about still remains. Can you tell me why even though the destructor is called twice (one from the object constructed before the assignment and one from after it), the id printed is the same?

Comment: @ShaheAnsar: When `A(std::string&& str)` is ran, your static variable is 1. That's trivially inspectable with a line-by-line debugger.

Comment: Yes, that means only one of the last two entries should be 1, the other one should be 0, why are both 1?

Comment: @ShaheAnsar. No. No. No. The compiler-generated *assignment operator* is called after the A(std::string&& str) constructor.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The title question:

> Do member variables die off before the destructor is called?

The answer is **No**. All member variables are alive in the body of the destructor.

Question in the post:

> The variable id is printed correctly by the included print function, but it fails with some other number when printed by the destructor, and the two are the same for both objects. Why does this happen?

That problem can be traced to the line:

```
a = std::string("World");
```

This calls the overloaded constructor of the class to create a temporary object and the temporary object is assigned to `a`. The problem here is the implementation of the constructor.

It used to be

```
A(std::string&& str)
{ 
   std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

The constructor left the member variable uninitialized. Hence, the value of member variable could be anything.

Now that you changed it to

```
A(std::string&& str)
{ 
   id = _idx;
  _idx++;
   std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

your program will work in a predictable manner.

#### Why are your last lines of output the way they are?

Consider the line

```
    a = std::string("World");
```

It is equivalent to:

1. Constructor a temporary object. (its `id` is 1)
2. Assign the temporary object to `a`. Now `a.id` is 1.
3. Destroy the temporary object. The destructor gets called on the temporary. You get the output 1

When the function returns, `a` is destructed. The destructor gets call on `a`. Since `a.id` is set to 1, you get the output 1.

Comment: The problem is, it doesn't. The last two entries still come out the same

Comment: @ShaheAnsar: Of course they are the same. `id = _idx;` happens before `_idx++`.

Comment: @R Sahu: I couldn't resist the edit. Upped for good feelings.

Comment: @Bathsheba How does that work? The destructor's being called two times, on different objects with different values of id, that means one should be 0, and the other should be 1

Comment: @Bathsheba, not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The destructor is called when the object needs to die. After the destructor runs, member variables are destructed in reverse order of declaration. Destructor runs first.

Answer (score 1):

> the two are the same for both objects. Why does this happen?

Because of this line.

```
a = std::string("World");
```

This constructs a **second `A`**, with `id = 1` and **assigns it** to the first `A` making that `id` also `1`.

That `=` is an *assignment operator*.  It means "make the left thing like the right thing".